# angular2 and nested child routes

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

WOW angular2 - nested routing is silly hard.

I have this route that shows this page:

```
 http://localhost:4200/#/dashboard(content:topline)

 <button (click)="onClick('top')">top</button>
 <router-outlet name="toplineul"></router-outlet>
```

Here is the routing:

```
{ path: 'topline',component: ToplineComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard], outlet:'content', children: [
      { path: 'top',component: TopComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard], outlet:'toplineul'}
  ]}
```

If I click the button on the topline page:

```
 onClick(event){

       if (event=='top'){
          this.router.navigateByUrl('/dashboard(content:topline//toplineul:top)');
       }
  }
```

This is the error I get:

```
EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'top'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'top'
    at ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:133966:16)
    at CatchSubscriber.selector (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:133935:29)
    at CatchSubscriber.error (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:72121:31)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._error (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:484:26)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.error (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:458:18)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._error (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:484:26)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.error (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:458:18)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._error (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:484:26)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.error (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:458:18)
    at LastSubscriber.Subscriber._error (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:484:26)
```

Comment: Totally clear that angular2 does not support nested outlets.  Angular2 devs...make more explicit that you not support this.

Answer (score 0):

Your mistakes

1. Your parent outlet had unclosed bracket.

   ```
   if (event=='top'){
         this.router.navigateByUrl('/dashboard(content:topline)//top/topline');
      }
   ```

Comment: ??? Is not child routes not in this format?  /dashboard(content:topline//toplineul:top)  What you posted did not work

Comment: the parent router outlet is content and this child outlet is toplineui